# Responsive legend font size in react-chartjs 2

Tags: chart.js, pie-chart, react-chartjs, legend-properties, react-chartjs-2

I have tried to make a pie chart using react-chartjs 2, It is working fine in desktop view but in mobile view the legend is not responsive it is taking much space and due to this the size of pie chart become very small.

my code:

```
function Chart(props: any) {
  const option = {
    tooltips: {enter image description here
      callbacks: {
        label: function (tooltipItem: any, data: any) {
          var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
          var meta = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]];
          var total = meta.total;
          var currentValue = dataset.data[tooltipItem.index];
          var percentage = parseFloat(
            ((currentValue / total) * 100).toFixed(1)
          );
          return currentValue + " (" + percentage + "%)";
        },
        title: function (tooltipItem: any, data: any) {
          return data.labels[tooltipItem[0].index];
        },
      },
    },
    legend: {
      display: true,
      labels: {
        fontSize: 12,
      },
      position: "right",
    },
  };

  return (
    <div className="chart">
      <Pie data={props.ChartData} options={option} />
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @Vikranth see my answer below if you are still looking for a way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can set your fontSize object as a ternery operator that checks the widts (or something else) to see if you are on a mobile device and give back the right fontSize according to it

If you want to update it real time because screen sizes change you can do that by mutating the chart options itself in a resizeEvent listner

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      labels: {
        fontSize: window.innerWidth > 350 ? 20 : 10
      }
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
const chart = new Chart(ctx, options);

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  if (window.innerWidth < 350) {
    chart.options.legend.labels.fontSize = 10;
  } else {
    chart.options.legend.labels.fontSize = 20
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js" integrity="sha512-hZf9Qhp3rlDJBvAKvmiG+goaaKRZA6LKUO35oK6EsM0/kjPK32Yw7URqrq3Q+Nvbbt8Usss+IekL7CRn83dYmw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way to have a responsive legend font size (also explained [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/fonts.html))

```
options: {
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                labels: {
                    // This more specific font property overrides the global property
                    font: {
                        size: 14
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```